# Jenkins behind Apache Server / Can't log in Jenkins

Tags: apache, authentication, jenkins

I'm running an Apache Server 2.2 to handle Jenkins and SonaType Nexus information (both installed as Windows Service). While SonatypeNexus runs perfectly Jenkins doesn't. To be more specific: I'can't log in Jenkins. Just for your notice: we are using LDAP to login, but this can't be the reason for login failure, as login from local host works.

If I try to log in Jenkins from `localhost:8071` it works perfectly.

When I log in from another system via network (using `https://myServer.com:8095/`) I can browse and configure Jenkins, but I can't login. Whenever I try I get "redirected" to the page of Jenkins I was on before hitting the "login" button.
Security settings are set to "everyone can do anything" -> can't be the reason either.

*Hint 0:* As you maybe already noticed we are using https for for any request from the outside dedicated to the server. But within the server Apache only uses http to handle information -> could this lead to problems?

*Hint 1:* I only get "redirected" using correct login parameters. Using wrong ones is leading me to the "Invalid login information. Please try again." page.

*Hint 2:* Sonatype Nexus is running behind the same Apache Server and works great.

*Potentional Reason:* guess the reason why I can login via localhost, but not via network must be  our Apache 2.2 server which is handling information wrong. By using localhost I can bypass Apache (-> works) but via network Apache gets used (-> don't work).

Any ideas how to fix this or at least what the reason could be?

Here are some settings from apache server (httpd-ssl.conf) that maybe could be useful:

```
<VirtualHost *:8095>
  ServerName myServer.com
  ServerAdmin admin@myServer.com  

  # Nexus via HTTPS.
  ProxyPass /nexus http://localhost:8072/nexus
  ProxyPassReverse /nexus http://localhost:8072/nexus
  ProxyPassReverseCookiePath / /nexus
  RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "https"
  ErrorLog logs/nexus_error_ssl.log
  CustomLog logs/nexus_access_ssl.log common

  # Jenkins via HTTPS.
  ProxyPass / http://localhost:8071/ nocanon
  ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8071/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://my.host.com/
  # also tested second ProxyPassReverse with specific port
  ProxyPassReverseCookiePath / /
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "https"


  ProxyRequests     Off
  AllowEncodedSlashes NoDecode  

  SSLEngine on
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if i describe my solution correct, since my collegue found the answer and not me.

Since the Apache was handling https (incomming from jenkins) correctly (requests reached LDAP), but was unable to pass http information (incomming from LDAP) correctly (login was unable).

So he took a look at the http settings and configured the settings to enable http. This was leading to our goal -> we can login now, **BUT** it also leads towards another problem -> http is enabled and usable for users...

Comment: I am facing the same problem. Can you please let me know what to change for http to be enabled?

Answer (score 0):

On [this](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Running+Jenkins+behind+Apache) page, it hints that you might need to add another ProxyPassReverse to fix http links generated by Jenkins:

```
ProxyPassReverse  /  http://your.host.com:8095/
```

Also, it mentions that you should add

```
ProxyPreserveHost On
```

to your config. Please check the link for further information.

Comment: thanks for the speedy response, but it did not help. Still got the same issue... (updated my questions description)